# How to make a text box in a command line window?

Tags: .net, command-line, boo

I'm working with .NET (specifically Boo, but answers would work in C# too) and I want to know how I could create an editable box inside the command line, such that I could display a section of output in the top part of the command line, and have a one line box at the bottom for input, much like the program irssi (the IRC client) does.

I assume this is possible with .NET, how would I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Console.SetCursorPosition(Column, Row)` to set the cursor to the appropriate position. For your example, use  `Console.SetCursorPosition(0,  Console.WindowHeight-1)` to place the cursor at the lower-most row and then let the user enter text.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't what you need a Windows application, with command-line client hosted inside of it?

Comment: Well, it *is* possible. It just might be more involved than the OP realizes.

Comment: True.  If you make a Windows application, you could do whatever you like with the layout, functionality, etc...

Answer (score 1):

`irssi` uses a library called `ncurses`, but in .Net, the [**System.Console**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console_members%28VS.80%29.aspx) object provides you with pretty much everything you need to make console-based applications.

Answer (score 0):

Another higher level option would be the [mono.curses](http://www.mono-project.com/MonoCurses) assembly.